# Apache Spark standalone settings

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have an Apache spark standalone set up.
I wish to start 3 workers to run in parallel: 
I use the commands below.

```
./start-master.sh 
SPARK_WORKER_INSTANCES=3 SPARK_WORKER_CORES=2 ./start-slaves.sh
```

I tried to run a few jobs and below are the apache UI results:

[image]

Ignore the last three applications that failed: Below are my questions:

1. Why do I have just one worker displayed in the UI despite asking spark to start 3 each with 2 cores?
2. I want to partition my input RDD for better performance. So for the first two jobs with no partions, I had a time of 2.7 mins. Here my Scala source code had the  following.

   `val tweets = sc.textFile("/Users/soft/Downloads/tweets").map(parseTweet).persist()`

In my third job (4.3 min) I had the below:

```
  val tweets = sc.textFile("/Users/soft/Downloads/tweets",8).map(parseTweet).persist()
```

I expected a shorter time with more partitions(8). Why was this the opposite of what was expected?

Answer (score 0):

1. Apparently you have only one active worker, which you need to investigate why other workers are not reported by checking the spark logs.
2. More partitions doesn't always mean that the application runs faster, you need to check how you are creating partitions from source data, the amount of data parition'd and how much data is being shuffled, etc.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are running on a local machine it is quite normal to just start a single worker with several CPU's as shown in the output. It will still split you task of the available CPU's in the machine.

Partitioning your file will happen automatically depending on the amount of available resources, it works quite well most of the time. Spark (and partitioning the files) comes with some overhead, so often, especially on a single machine Spark adds so much overhead it will slowdown you process. The added values comes with large amounts of data on a cluster of machines.

Assuming that you are starting a stand-alone cluster, I would suggest using the configuration files to setup a the cluster and use `start-all.sh` to start a cluster.

1. first in your `spark/conf/slaves` (copied from `spark/conf/slaves.template` add the IP's (or server names) of you worker nodes.
2. configure the `spark/conf/spark-defaults.conf` (copied from `spark/conf/spark-defaults.conf.template` Set at least the master node to the server that runs your master.
3. Use the `spark-env.sh` (copied from `spark-env.sh.template`) to configure the cores per worker, memory etc:

```
export SPARK_WORKER_CORES="2"
export SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY="6g"
export SPARK_DRIVER_MEMORY="4g"
export SPARK_REPL_MEM="4g"
```

4. Since it is standalone (and not hosted on a Hadoop environment) you need to share (or copy) the configuration (or rather the complete spark directory) to all nodes in your cluster. Also the data you are processing needs to be available on all nodes e.g. directly from a bucket or a shared drive.

As suggested by the @skjagini checkout the various log files in `spark/logs/` to see what's going on. Each node will write their own log files.

See https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-standalone.html for all options.

(*we have a setup like this running for several years and it works great!*)

Comment: Partitioning the file doesn't happen automatically, if the file happens to be on hdfs, as hdfs already maintains the data in blocks, Spark can read those blocks as partitions  otherwise its not always the case

Comment: I managed to use this command " ./bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker spark://Softs-MacBook-Pro.local:7077". Each time you run it, it creates a worker attached to the master. However, all created workers now have 7GB of memory. I run it three times and the spark UI indicates memory in use as 21GB. My mac has just 8GB of RAM. However, when I submit a job, all the three workers are seen to be acting on it. Should I expect a speedup from my previous set up with one worker?

Comment: So you might want to try to lower the memory of you workers, set the worker `SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY` at 1GB and the `SPARK_WORKER_CORES` at 1. But really this will only help you testing a spark cluster and not necessarily speed up the process.